# errors in passing 2-Dimesional array in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing

```
int *mergeKArrays(int arr[][n], int k)  <--[see below for errors at this line]
{
int *output=new int[n*k];
}
```

In the above function, I have not included full definition here, as it is of no use for finding error.

Main function is like this where I am calling mergeKArrays function.

```
int main()
{
  int arr[][n]={{2, 6, 12, 34},
                 {1, 9, 20, 1000},
                 {23, 34, 90, 2000}};
  int k = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

  int *output = mergeKArrays(arr, k);
}
```

now the errors I am getting are at the line of function definition are like this.

```
error: 'n' was not declared in this scope.

error: expected ')' before ',' token

error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
```

Pardon me, if I have asked a trivial question, but right now I am unable to figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ... so where did you declare `n`?

Comment: in int arr[][n],
n is declared like this only, when we pass 2-Dimensional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message

> error: 'n' was not declared in this scope

is enough clear. The compiler does not see the declaration of n.

Take into account that the size of an array shall be a constant expression. So n in your code shall be declared as a constant object.

Comment: Thanks I got it ! I should have written at the top of my program, something like "const int n = 3;" then it would have worked. My bad !

Comment: @Geek_Akash According to your code snippet n has to be defined as equal to 4. It is k that will be equal to 3.

Comment: yup, it(n=3) was for illustration only. Thanks a lot.